# Namespace commands configure veth0 with a 169.254.x.y address

Tags: networking

While experimenting with Namespace setup found that the following commands consistently configure veth0 with a 169.254.x.y address. I've checked everywhere in the system and cannot find a reference to it.

Any ideas on what is going on here or could be causing this?

```
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
sudo ip netns add myvpn
sudo ip link set veth1 netns myvpn
sudo ip addr add dev veth0 192.168.2.1/24 broadcast 192.168.2.255
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add dev veth1 192.168.2.2/24 broadcast 192.168.2.255
sudo ip link set veth0 up
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip link set veth1 up

$ ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.2 metric 202 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth0 scope link src 169.254.104.159 metric 205 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 202 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 303 
192.168.2.0/24 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on Link-local Address says that "RFC 3927, the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) has reserved the IPv4 address block 169.254.0.0/16 (169.254.0.0 – 169.254.255.255) for link-local addressing" so my issue is probably related to dhcp configuration, a separate issue from this post.